# Get depth value in JOGL

Tags: java, jogl

First of all, I'm new on coding 3D-Graphics, and I hope this isn't a too stupid question.

I need to draw a depth map on a simple shape with JOGL. To draw this shape, I have followed this tutorial here:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jogl/jogl_3d_triangle.htm

Now I want to display the colours on this shape according on the distance of each fragment to the focus point, pretty much on what is shown here:
https://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-OpenGL/Depth-testing
section *Visualizing the depth buffer*.

While there they just use the *gl_FragCoord.z* value, I somehow fail to find the equivalent in JOGL.

Does someone know how to access this value? Or maybe I have to use some other approach?

Thankyou very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Because it's GLSL keyword. You must to write your own shader for using this value.